# How to install PHP module intl on Ubunut 22.04 with both PHP 8.1 and PHP 8.2 active

Tags: php, module, intl

My WordPress website site health page displays possible improvement — PHP module intl missing.

[image: 1]

My server has multiple versions of PHP (8.1 &8.2) active.

I use the following ssh command to install the missing intl module:

```
apt-get install -y php-intl
```

But I get this error message:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  php8.1-intl :
> Depends: php8.1-common (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.10) but
> 8.1.14-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

The PHP modules which are active on my server, like imagick, are installed for php8.1. But my active PHP version is 8.2.

[image: 2]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the dependencies of the "php8.1-intl" package. Specifically, it requires version 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.10 of the "php8.1-common" package, but the version that is currently available is 8.1.14-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, which is causing a conflict.

try:

1. `sudo apt update`
2. `sudo apt-get check`
3. `sudo apt-get install -f`
4. `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

5.`sudo apt-get install php8.1-common=8.1.2-1ubuntu2.10`

6.`sudo apt-get install php8.1-intl`

You may need to remove the conflicting package(s) and installing the required packages again. But be careful when removing packages as it may cause other dependencies to break.

Comment: I tried the method as listed above, also removed the package and reinstalled it. in both cases got the admn screen error showing php code throughout its length.

Comment: I hvave three versions of php installed on my server ( php.7.2, php8.1, and php8.2). If i remove php7.2  I again get the php code displayed instead of admin area.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is that the server was upgraded from Ubuntu **20** to **22**. I'm using `PHP8.2` and already have a running web server.

When I install the `php-intl` using `sudo apt install php-intl`,
it gives me the version for `8.1` which I don't need.

But when I directly install `php8.2-intl` It does not exist on that repository.

So I added the PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
```

After that, I ran the command to install the `php-intl`

```
sudo apt install php8.2-intl
```

It ran flawlessly, and so did the installed apps.